# CorePlot/CorePlot.h not found

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a problem compiling core-plot 0.9 examples in XCode 3.2.6 for ios.
The problem starts in the Controller.h on this line

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>
```

and the compiler says CorePlot/CorePlot.h not found.
I followed the README for static Library Install.rtf so I have a CorePlotHeaders folder in the project and libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a in Link Binary With Libraries folder.

Comment: What example are you trying to compile? Only the Mac sample applications use `#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>` to reference the headers in the Mac framework.  The iOS examples all use `#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"` for the iOS static library.  You may also find the instructions on the project wiki to be more helpful: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: Ah, I'm terribly sorry, I apologize for taking your time. I tried to compile DatePlot for ios. I succeded to get the ios-example to run. So I'm happy now. /Jan Gifvars

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```